# I'm trying to split text from numbers and sum up total amount from the last numbers

Tags: numbers, shortcuts-app

I build an shortcut that helps me following my medicine consumption and I want to get info once/two a day regarding the total amount I consumes at the same day/In the last week and so on.
This is how it looks in notes:
[image: note screenshot]

> 12.07 12:19 - 1,3ml
> 21.07 12:44  - 2,6ml
> 21.07 13:00 - 2ml
> 21.07 13:04 - 2ml
> 20.09 15:38 - 3ml
> 20.09 17:24 - 3ml
> 21.09 08:29 - 3ml
> 21.09 10:46 - 1,5ml
> 21.09 11:28 - 1,6ml
> 21.09 18:21 - 3ml
> 28.09 06:26 -0ml
> 28.09 06:29 -2ml
> 28.09 06:29 -2ml
> 28.09 06:30 -2ml

So im trying to sum only the ml numbers at the end of each line (ml) will be awesome to separate by date  but ill be happy with just calculating the ml amount in total.

Comment: Notes doesn't do any sort of calculations.  If you need to do this, then you need a different tool like a spreadsheet (Excel or Numbers)

Comment: What about creating shortcut with split text and pull only those numbers for calculation

Comment: I’ll not sure what you mean by that. Do you want this for macOS or iOS?  Also “pull only...”?  How do you see the workflow operating?  Like how would you define “split text”?  How would it get split and into what format and where would it come from?

Comment: Sorry for the poor English

It's for iOS, I want to split the txt from this note using shortcuts and get only the ml numbers and sum.